# QGIS DXF measurements in AutoCAD are in Cartesian and not Ellipsoidal

Tags: qgis, scale, dxf, ellipsoid, cartesian

I'm trying to export some land boundary polygons to AutoCAD using the Export to DXF function.

The issue I am having is that the distance measurements in AutoCAD, of the exported DXF file, represent the same values I get when I select the cartesian option in QGIS measurement and that does not represent the actual land dimensions, I would like to get the ellipsoidal measurements instead, which also match the measurements I get using Google Earth.

I have tried to export the DXF into different CRS, such as EPSG:3857, EPSG:4326 and EPSG:32600 (UTM), but I got the same dimensions.

See images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please state which CRS your data is in, as well as where the landplot is situated, because changing between cartesian & ellipsodial shouldn't result in such an error if you chose the correct CRS.

Comment: @Erik thanks for the tip, that really solved the issue! The data uses British National Grid, and when I changed everything to that CRS, the cartesian and ellipsoisal distances became very similar. I did not expect that to be the problem as I thought QGIS could convert from British NG to my project CRS (EPSG:3857).

Comment: QGIS can do so. The issue is/was, that 3857 covers the whole globe and therefore is not that accurate.

Comment: Thank you, that's been very helpful.